# Is it possible to let both "registered users" and "un-registered users" post a comment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to allow both "registered users" and "un-registered users" post a comment.
Currently, my application is running fine, and it's based on only registered user system(only registered users can post comments)

I'm planning to change this system to more public(un-registered users can post comments)

How can I archive that? What should I add to my current system?

---

I do have `User` model, and `Comment`model.

In `Comment` model, it has `user_id` column, and associations are defined just like this

**models/user.rb**

```
has_many: comments
```

**models/comment.rb**

```
belongs_to: user
```

Then `comment create action` is just like this.

```
....
@comment = Comment.build_from(commentable, current_user.try(:id), params[:comment][:body])  
@comment.title = params[:comment][:title]
@comment.save
....
```

**views/comments/show.html.erb**

```
<% if !comment.user_id.nil? %>
    <%= comment.user.nickname %>
<% else %>
    guest
<% end %>
```

Comment: Can you post your `Comment.build_from` method?

Comment: Is this code not working?

Comment: @SergeyKishenin Thanks for reply:) I'm using the gem, and it has that class. It should be somewhere in here `https://github.com/elight/acts_as_commentable_with_threading`

Comment: @santhosh Nah. I get this error:( ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Mysql2::Error: Column 'user_id' cannot be null: INSERT INTO `comments` (`body`, `body_html`, `comment_icon_content_type`, `comment_icon_file_name`, `comment_icon_file_size`, `comment_icon_updated_at`, `commentable_id`, `commentable_type`, `created_at`, `deleted_at`, `lft`, `parent_id`, `rgt`, `subject`, `title`, `updated_at`, `user_id`) VALUES ('test', '<p>test</p>', NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, 12, 'Topic', '2013-05-18 12:11:15', NULL, 145, NULL, 146, '', NULL, '2013-05-17 10:11:15', NULL)):

Comment: You have `validates :user, :presence => true` line in `Comment` model so you can try remove it but you couldn't use some methods provided by this gem. Also you have to pass nil unless ou have valid user in `build_from` method like `def self.build_from(obj, user_id=nil, comment)`. That's not the best idea, I guess

Comment: Jus noticed that `Comment` model was not generated so you have to override it to customize.

Comment: @MKK What is that at the end of the error message? `NULL)):` Is that part of the query, or is that a stupid frowny face?